# Apache ErrorLogFormat: Log only IPs without ports

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, fail2ban

for a modified fail2ban I need to customize my apache error.log. I want Apache to log only the IP adresses, not the ports (usually used for NATting).
I discovered the ErrorLogFormat directive but as far as I can see there is only the `%a` variable that is the whole IP + port. Is there a way to separate these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by manually installing a the fail2ban beta version which supports IPv6. That was what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, with so many NATs, it is almost mandatory to log both IP address and port, having just the address is often not enough.

For your specific problem you should just create another "normal" (not error) logfile, using `CustomLog` and you then have a far richer set of expansions available, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

There, a `%a` will give you only the IP.

Comment: Yes, but a CutomLog won't log only errors and thats a bad practice when working with fail2ban.

Comment: What kind of error? You will get all http error codes...